# How do I deploy to Heroku in vapor4

Tags: heroku, vapor

When I finish to deploy my vapor app to Heroku. But my app didn't actually work on the url I made in Heroku. The url is worked, but the action couldn't be take. I think my DATABASE_URL cannot be configured.And I don't know how to fix this. If there is something I need to add please tell me.

```swift
import Vapor
import Fluent
import FluentPostgresDriver
import FluentPostGIS

import Vapor

extension Environment {
    
    static var databaseURL: URL {
        guard let urlString = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL"), let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            fatalError("DATABASE_URL not configured")
        }
        return url
    }
}
// configures your application
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    // uncomment to serve files from /Public folder
    // app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))

    app.migrations.add(CreateUser())
    app.migrations.add(CreateInfo())
    app.migrations.add(CreateUserToken())
    app.sessions.use(.fluent)

    
    app.databases.use(.postgres(hostname: "localhost", username: "postgres", password: "", database: "template1"), as: .psql)
     
    try routes(app)
    
}
```

Comment: What do the logs say and have you configured a DB in Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

For your reference: https://github.com/mobile-dev-enginner/TILAPP

- Command: heroku login -> heroku config